# What is the difference between Adding ICollection and Simply adding a field to store a key to another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the difference between two sets of Code First Models in the following code. I believe that the first way is practiced generally. But I also find the second method easier because we just have to store a key to the item related to the other table. Are there any advantages of using it in comparison to the second way? I would be happy to clear any confusions in the question. Thanks.

Method 1 :

```
public class Blog{
public int BlogId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Category {get;set;}
public ICollection<Post> Posts{get;set;}
}


public class Post{
public int PostId{get;set;}
public string Contents {get;set;}
public DateTime Date{get;set;}
public string Author {get;set;}
public Blog Blog {get;set;}
}
```

Method 2:

```
public class Blog{
public int BlogId {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Category {get;set;}
}


public class Post{
public int PostId{get;set;}
public string Contents {get;set;}
public DateTime Date{get;set;}
public string Author {get;set;}
public int BlogId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This may help you understand things better http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the primary difference is of course that there's no way to directly access a blog's posts from a `Blog` instance with the second method. If you want to get that blog's posts, you'd have to issue a separate query like:

```
db.Posts.Where(m => m.BlogId == blog.BlogId)
```

The other thing this does is prohibit Entity Framework's ability to either lazy or eager load a blog's posts. For example, with the first method, you could do something like:

```
var blog = db.Blogs.Include("Posts").SingleOrDefault(m => m.BlogId == blogId);
```

By doing that, you would then be able to iterate through the blog's `Posts` collection without having to issue another query to the database; Entity Framework would do a join to include the posts all in one query.

Further, if you added `virtual` to that collection property:

```
public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

You could lazy-load the result set, so that given:

```
var blog = db.Blogs.Find(blogId);
```

You could immediately do something like:

```
foreach (var post in blog.Posts)
{
    // whatever
}
```

It would issue another query to the database to retrieve the `Posts` collection at that point, but you wouldn't have to worry about explicitly querying for the posts that belong to that blog as the first code example above showed.

Comment: Can we really create a relationship between `Blog` on `Post` with the second method?

Comment: So the main difference is the efficiency and achieving the entity frameworks features ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Sure. The relationship is already there. `Post` has a foreign key to `Blog` through `BlogId`. There's your relationship.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Are you sure it's not just a normal column? How to let EF `know` that `BlogId` is a foreign key? How to configure that?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire: Pretty much. Your POCO is just a public API. If the collection is something that should never be access directly, then it's acceptable to leave the collection property off. However, accessing the posts of a blog is something that really should have a public API, so in this scenario, the correct approach should be to include it. The EF stuff is gravy.

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Well, I think the confusion here lies in the correlation between EF and your database. You could totally manage a relationship with just an id property, but you would have to manage it. You're right that there's nothing here to tell EF what to do with, but at the database-level it would work. If you want EF to manage the relationship you'd need to add an actual `Blog` property, though.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, check my answer, I could not create a relationship between `Blog` and `Post` with EF code first, would you mind update my answer to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I like your second approach better frankly.  I don't care for the circular references between Blog and Post illustrated by the first example.  This isn't really an answer, but an opinion.  Your second approach maps more cleanly to a RDMBS.

The first looks like an auto-generated product of the Entity Framework, where the Blog is aware of its child posts but the child itself is fully aware of its associated Blog.  This kind of parent to child / child to parent dynamic is found in ADO.NET with a DataTable that has child rows, and then the row itself can be traced back to the fully loaded parent table.  I think it lends itself to heavier objects and more references on the heap.

I'd stick with the second approach, and then have some kind of aggregate object that includes the Blog and a collection of Posts separately.

```
public class BlogWithPosts
{
    public Blog @Blog { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hey Mark, Thanks for the opinion. Have you ever had a chance to practice the second approach before? It seems to me that most of the things that can be achieved using fancy way, can be achieved using the second intuitive approach... What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is invalid.

With the second method, how come you create a relationship between `Blog` and `Post`?
You either need to provide `Post` collection on `Blog` or `Blog` reference on `Post`.

I still don't understand with the OP second method.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Compile error, the type int must be a reference type...
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(p => p.BlogId).WithMany();
    }
}
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The property referenced by `HasRequired` must be an entity type, not a key. Like I said in my comment under the question, you'd have to add a `Blog` property if you wanted EF to manage the relationship, i.e. `public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }`. That's enough on its own; you wouldn't need to define anything for `OnModelCreating`.

Comment: `you'd have to add a Blog property if you wanted EF to manage the relationship`, exactly, but in the OP second method, there is no `Blog` reference in there, by convention EF will not consider `BlogId` as foreign key, even by fluent api we can't do that.. that's all I wanted to say, the second method is simply invalid, database relationship will not be able to be created